# Multi threaded function already defined in .obj

Tags: multithreading, c++11, visual-c++, lnk2005

I've searched for the error LNK2005 "already defined in .obj" but can't find content related to the specific problem I am facing. Hope someone can help me on this...

I've a header **foo.h**

```
// foo.h

#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void foo() {
    print("foo\n");
}

#endif
```

and main file... **main.cpp**

```
// main.cpp

#include <thread>
#include "foo.h"

int main() {

    std::thread t(foo);
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Now, it compile **without** any **errors** and gives the **gives output** to the console...

```
foo
```

But if I create another file **foo.cpp** and just include the header **foo.h** and do nothing else...

```
// foo.cpp

#include "foo.h"
```

...I get linker error LNK2005 "void __cdecl foo(void)" (?foo@@YAXXZ) already defined in main.obj

Don't know what's going wrong here.?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must place only the prototype of the foo() function in the header file, and the implementation once in the .cpp.

Thus, foo.h must contain:

```
#pragma once
void foo();
```

And foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo() {
    printf("Whatever");
}
```